# Does mass affect the amplitude in a mass-spring-damper system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, friction, spring, oscillators

I couldn't find a similar question here and some answers online were contradictory so I hope that we can clear this out here.

So, does amplitude depend on mass for a mass-spring-damper system? If not, why not?

My understanding is that mass should not affect the amplitude, only the initial energy provided to the system will affect it.

Answer (score 1):

The rate of decay of amplitude depends on the mass as $\sim e^{-t/m}$ just like a [regular damped oscillator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-spring-damper_model).

Comment: the factor $e^{-t/m}$ is not dimensionless so cannot be right.

Comment: I’ve shabbily clubbed it into the prefactor. But yes, it is a not-so-neat convention.